# Rubyで二重ループを使ったファイル読み込み時に想定通り動作しない

Tags: ruby

基本的なことかもしれませんが、おしえてください。
同一ファイル内での同じ文言をチェックするスクリプトを作成したいです。
↓のように作ってみたのですが、想定通り動作しません。

lineを出力してみたところ1行目のデータのみ出力され、2行目以降が出力されない状態です。

すいませんが、ご教授下さい。

```
file_name = 'check.txt'
r = File.open(file_name)

File.foreach(file_name) do |line|
  r.each do |line2|
    puts line # → 一行目がrの行数分出力されるのみ
  end
end

r.close
```

Comment: 一回目のループの実行でファイルの終端まで達していますので、`r.each do ~ end` の直後で `r.rewind`(先頭まで巻き戻す)を実行すれば良いかと。

Comment: 想定通り動きました！本当に感謝です。ありがとうございました。

Comment: …よくよく考えたら一度配列で読み込んでチェックすれば済む話でしたね。すいませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r.each`を(途中で`berak`することなく)最後まで実行すると、`r`は最後まで読み込んだことになります(読み込み位置がEOFに達している)。その後、`r.each`が再び実行されても、既に最後まで読み込んでいるため、一行も読み込まれず、処理全体がスキップされます。

再度、最初から読み直したい場合は、@metropolis さんの書いているとおり、`r.rewind`で読み込み位置を先頭に戻してください。